# Azure mltable throwing ImportError when it is imported in Azure Notebooks in AutoML

Tags: python, azure

I am writing code in the notebooks on Azure AutoML wtih Spark Version 3.2 which means that Python version is 3.8.

I have installed the mltable in Azure Notebooks using the command:

```
%pip install -U mltable azureml-dataprep[pandas]
```

Before installing mltable I had already installed azure-ai-ml package as well. But still mltable is throwing import error when I try to import it using:

```
import mltable
```

It throws the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_23522/3630867241.py in <module>
     16 from azure.ai.ml.entities import AmlCompute
     17 
---> 18 import mltable
     19 import os

/nfs4/pyenv-da563906-c8c8-4c39-89f1-22def948bc6a/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mltable/__init__.py in <module>
      9 any Python environment, including Jupyter Notebooks or your favorite Python IDE.
     10 """
---> 11 from .mltable import MLTable, load, from_delimited_files, from_parquet_files, from_json_lines_files, from_paths, \
     12     from_delta_lake, DataType, MLTableFileEncoding, MLTableHeaders
     13 

/nfs4/pyenv-da563906-c8c8-4c39-89f1-22def948bc6a/lib/python3.8/site-packages/mltable/mltable.py in <module>
     20 from azureml.dataprep.api._constants import ACTIVITY_INFO_KEY, ERROR_CODE_KEY, \
     21     COMPLIANT_MESSAGE_KEY, OUTER_ERROR_CODE_KEY
---> 22 from azureml.dataprep.api._dataframereader import get_dataframe_reader, to_pyrecords_with_preppy, \
     23     _execute
     24 from azureml.dataprep.api.mltable._mltable_helper import _download_mltable_yaml, _parse_path_format, _PathType, \

ImportError: cannot import name 'to_pyrecords_with_preppy' from 'azureml.dataprep.api._dataframereader' (/home/trusted-service-user/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/azureml/dataprep/api/_dataframereader.py)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not able to find solution but I did find one workaround. Instead of using Auto ML SDK V2, try to use Auto ML SDK V1. azure-ai-ml and azure-identity packages are part of SDK V2. Therefore, do not install them in Azure Notebooks or on local environment if you are using that.

To use SDK V1 install following packages as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/overview/azure/ml/install?view=azure-ml-py&preserve-view=true :

1. pip install azureml-core
2. pip install azureml-automl-core
3. pip install azureml-train-automl (for local environment)
4. pip install azureml-train-automl-client (thin client for remote computer)